# Reshaping Data from an XML converted table

Tags: r, xml, reshape, data-mining, data-cleaning

I have got a data-frame converted from XML to csv. Now the problem is I need to make an excel sheet out of this data but the data is a complete mess. I was wondering if you could help to find the R codes to solve the problem.

I explain the problem in detail. Imagine if the dataset is something like that:

```
student.data <- data.frame(id = c(1:17),
                       student_id = c(1111,"","","","","","","","","2222","","","","","","",""),
                       exam_id =c("",10,10,20,20,20,30,40,40,"",10,10,10,20,30,40,40), 
                       status = c("","AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","FFF","GGG","AAA","GGG","","BBB","HHH","MMM","FFF","DDD","GGG","GGG"))
```

the result must be:

[image]
I know for a fact that it is a bit complicated but thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: @akrun I am afraid not since this is big data and the result is bigger than imagination

Comment: Not looking for your entire data.  Just few rows that you think would be a reproducible example with expected output.  thanks

Comment: If the column blanks are `NA`, then `library(dplyr);library(tidyr); df1 %>% fill(col1) %>% group_by(col1) %>% slice(-1) %>% group_by(col2, add = TRUE) %>% summarise(col3 = toString(col3)) %>% ungroup %>% pivot_wider(names_from = col2, values_from = col3)`

Comment: Please let me know iff the code works because it is just from my imagination about your data and not tested

Comment: thank you very much but it is not working unfortunately. I will try to explain my dataset better.@akrun

Comment: okay, then it is because of the data.  If it is a `dput`, then others can test their code.

Comment: @akrun I have changed the data-frame format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the blank (`""`). elements in 'student_id' to `NA` (`na_if`), then use `fill` to replace the NA elements with the adjacent non-NA element, grouped by 'student_id', 'exam_id', get the `unique` elements of 'status' that are not a blank (`""`) and paste it to a single string (`toString`), `filter` out any rows where there are blanks and reshape the output to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
student.data %>% 
  mutate(student_id = na_if(student_id, "")) %>%
 fill(student_id) %>%
 group_by(student_id, exam_id) %>% 
 summarise(status  =  toString(unique(status[status!= '']))) %>% 
 filter_at(vars(exam_id, status), any_vars(. != '')) %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = exam_id, values_from = status)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   student_id [3]
#  student_id `10`          `20`          `30`  `40`    
#  <fct>      <chr>         <chr>         <chr> <chr>   
#1 1111       AAA, BBB      CCC, DDD, FFF GGG   AAA, GGG
#2 2222       BBB, HHH, MMM FFF           DDD   GGG
```

Comment: thanks for your cooperate. I truly appreciate your help. It worked pretty much well.